# Need to log a script execution on users machine

Tags: vbscript

```
'Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

logfile = "\\\\ja-rfzitd\INSTDIR\000 Sephora - UAT\RPAS_Implementation\LogFile\" & net.UserName &      "_" & net.ComputerName & ".log"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logfile, 8, True)
f.WriteLine "Script executed at" & Now
f.WriteLine "The User Name is " & net.username & "
f.WriteLine "The Netbios name is " & net.ComputerName &"

f.Close'
```

Can you check and let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Why do you define more than one `WScript.Shell` object? _To create a log file on the network share_: the [OpenTextFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) allows UNC paths to filenames.

Comment: Using a log file on a share may create more problem than it solves, because when some user is currently writing to the file, opening the file will fail for other users until the file is closed by the first user. What is the purpose of this log file? Do you want to record which clients have run the script?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Agree, but... No doubt we could write a _fool-proof_ error-handling  procedure, if there is a need of (or a want of) logging anything in a log file on a share.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for your prompt response. All I want is, the script to should report back to me once its executed on any user machine. And I thought a log file would be the right way of doing it. Now, I am using the share (Where all users have read and write access) to deploy the script through a hyperlink. So am sure there should'nt be any issue writing the log file to share. Also, I am not thinking about creating a single file and append the same file , but create individual file for each user by their host name or usrname. I hope you can help me on this

Comment: @JosefZ Make something foolproof and nature will provide you with an improved fool.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I cannot choose but agree :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to create an individual logfile per user and computer:

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

logfile = "\\server\share\" & net.UserName & "_" & net.ComputerName & ".log"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logfile, 8, True)
f.WriteLine "information you want to log"
f.Close
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a bunch, I tried the below but its something is wrong in it, can u please check."Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

logfile = "\\\\ja-rfzitd\INSTDIR\000 Sephora - UAT\RPAS_Implementation\LogFile\" & net.UserName & "_" & net.ComputerName & ".log"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(logfile, 8, True)
f.WriteLine "Script executed at" & Now
f.WriteLine "The User Name is " & net.username & "
f.WriteLine "The Netbios name is " & net.ComputerName &"

f.Close"

Comment: @JamsheerMeethal Please do not post code in comments. As you can see it becomes a mess. Instead edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Can you please check the code I posted on the origianl question field. I think I made a mistake by editing my origial question, anyways, like I requested, M really in need of it as I have to deploy the script tomorrow.

Comment: @JamsheerMeethal Remove `& "` from the end of lines 8 and 9. `&` is the string concatenation operator in VBScript, and `"` is the delimiter for strings, i.e. you're trying to concatenate an incomplete string to the rest of the line, which naturally raises an error.

Comment: @JamsheerMeethal Addendum: also change `\\\\ja-rfzitd` into `\\ja-rfzitd`. Normally you don't need to escape backslashes in VBScript. There are some exceptions (nameley WMI and regular expressions), but they don't apply here.